# APNS when not in app causes sever lag/crash

Tags: ios, node.js, xcode, swift2, apple-push-notifications

I am sending a push notification from my node-js server. I set the badge count to 1. It works fine when my app is in the foreground, `didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken` gets called and the app does what I want. What I want is a UI action, basically something that the user has to do. However, if I lock my phone and then do this notification, it doesn't show the UI. I know it has called the notification because it says failed, and it lags the app/phone severely. Does anyone know how I can get this UI element to pop up and not lag the phone when the push notification happens?

Thanks

Comment: You need to show some code.

Comment: I'm not sure what code I can show that would be beneficial. Basically, I am trying to access something in the keychain when this happens. That thing is locked via a touchID, so the person needs to do a touchID to get this out when the notification is sent. That is failing and returning an error, the touchID never shows up.

Comment: Well, push notifications don't cause apps to loop/crash, so it must be something in your code. Show the code you run when you receive the remote notification? What crash do you get?  What does the stack trace look like? Can you reproduce this under the debugger?  Where does the "failed" message come from?  What happens after you print that?

Comment: I get a errSecAuthFailed OSStatus error code from the TouchID. Obviously the authentication fails, because the TouchID doesn't even show up. I am calling the function that accesses the keychain from the app delegate, could this be the reason the UI doesn't load.

Comment: Right, but that on its own won't  be enough to lag the phone/app.  Without seeing your code there is nothing that anyone can do to help

Comment: I am using SecItemCopyMatching. When I insert into the keychain, I set the control flags like this: SecAccessControlCreateFlags.TouchIDCurrentSet. This means the keychain Item is locked in the keychain. I now want to get this item out, which means the person has to do a touchID. When I call SecItemCopyMatching it returns errSecAuthFailed because there is no touchID prompt able to be shown.

Comment: How about you do the authentication when the app comes back in foreground

Comment: We can't tell you how to change your code, because you *haven't shown any code*

Answer (score -1):

You must add the `UIStatusBarStyleBlackTranslucent` option:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleLightContent | UIStatusBarStyleBlackTranslucent];
```

If you set this calling, UI will be entered when moving from background or locking to the foreground.

Comment: I don't think you understood the question properly.I don't think status bar is related to the issue here